# Javascript replace tag but preserve content

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

Say i have a text like this:

`This should also be extracted, <strong>text</strong>`

I need the `text` only from the entire string, I have tried this:

`r = r.replace(/<strong[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/strong>/g, "$1");` but failed (`strong` is still there). Is there any proper way to do this?

**Expected Result**

`This should also be extracted, text`

**Solution:**

To target specific tag I used this:

`r = r.replace(/<strong\b[^>]*>([^<>]*)<\/strong>/i, "**$1**")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
var r = "This should also be extracted, <strong>text</strong>";
r = r.replace(/<(.+?)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/,"$2");
console.log(r);
```

I have just included some strict regex. But if you want relaxed version, you can very well do

```
r = r.replace(/<.+?>/g,"");
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to only regex only on strong tag with your code?

Comment: Thanks, see solution, I have able to target specific tag only

Comment: @user2002495 don't forget to accept any answer which helped you the most

Comment: This does, of course, fail with `<strong data-attr="hey look: > ">text</strong>` Hence needing to parse.

Comment: I don't need to check for attributes, since basically I control the entire DOM elements itself in an uneditable iframe, I just need to be able to do what I want

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, yeah.. won't answer any more of these :)

Answer (score 3):

To parse HTML, you need an HTML parser. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for why.

If you just want to remove `<strong>` and `</strong>` from the text, you don't need parsing, but of course simplistic solutions tend to fail, which is why you need an HTML parser to parse HTML. Here's a simplistic solution that removes `<strong>` and `</strong>`:

```
str = str.replace(/<\/?strong>/g, "")
```

```js
var yourString = "This should also be extracted, <strong>text</strong>";
yourString = yourString.replace(/<\/?strong>/g, "")
display(yourString);

function display(msg) {
  // Show a message, making sure any HTML tags show
  // as text
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Back to parsing: In your case, you can easily do it with the browser's parser, if you're on a browser:

```js
var yourString = "This should also be extracted, <strong>text</strong>";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = yourString;
display(div.innerText || div.textContent);

function display(msg) {
  // Show a message, making sure any HTML tags show
  // as text
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Most browsers provide `innerText`; Firefox provides `textContent`, which is why there's that `||` there.

In a non-browser environment, you'll want some kind of DOM library (there are lots of them).

Comment: I am not parsing the html, i just need the text without the <strong> tag shown in a text document later

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Right :-) I didn't see that!

Comment: @user2002495: To reliably get the content within HTML tags, you have to parse HTML. It's as simple as that. Attempts to use simplistic rules *will* fail.

Comment: Thanks for all the answer, in the end I solved it on my own, but all your answers seems enlightening

Comment: @user2002495: FWIW, for just `strong` and without attributes (based on your comments elsewhere), I did add a regex example.